# SQL Syntax errors on my update and insert statements

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, jet

I wrote simple update/insert statements that are returning a syntax error, what am I missing? The table name is notes, the field note is type memo, acaps is a double.

```
update notes set note='why is there a syntax error' where acaps=12345
```

Syntax error on my insert statement too:

```
insert into notes (acaps,note,updated,userId) values (12345,'Why is there a syntax error',#6/13/2011 5:07:35 PM#,'BRSANDE')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are attempting to use a reserved word:  [List of reserved words in Access 2002 and in later versions of Access](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/286335)

```
update [notes]
set [note] = 'why is there a syntax error' 
where [acaps] = 12345


insert into [notes] ([acaps], [note], [updated], [userId]) 
values (12345, 'Why is there a syntax error', #6/13/2011 5:07:35 PM#, 'BRSANDE')
```

Comment: Ok I really need to study those reserved keywords, tripped me up again. Thanks!